# Regex expression to parse string

Tags: java, regex, string

String: `'Purchase Appln : 2157551 - DIRECT 1,23.00 1,234.23'`

Output result should be

`str1 = 'Purchase Appln : 2157551 - DIRECT';`

`str2= '1,23.00 1,234.23';`

Please help me to create a regex expression to get that desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Use positive lookaround with `String.split` method:

```
String input = "Purchase Appln : 2157551 - DIRECT 1,23.00 1,234.23";
String[] result = input.split("(?<=DIRECT) ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Will print that you need

```
[Purchase Appln : 2157551 - DIRECT, 1,23.00 1,234.23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String str = "Purchase Appln : 2157551 - DIRECT 1,23.00 1,234.23";

String str1 = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("DIRECT" + 6); //str1 = 'Purchase Appln : 2157551 - DIRECT';

String str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf("DIRECT" + 7);    //str2= '1,23.00 1,234.23';
```